# Ember component ignoring height / overflow

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

I'm trying to make an ember component that will scroll to the bottom of its self when it's loaded (it's the view for a chat window)

I got the component:

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didRender() {
    const el = this.$('.chat-window');
    el.scrollTop(el[0].scrollHeight);
  }
});
```

and then the component hbs file

```
<div class="chat-window">
    {{yield}}
</div>
```

and then the template view

```
  {{#chat-window}}
    {{chat-message username="John Doe" message="Blah Blah Blah" dispic="http://www.proirrigationwi.com/images/unknown_user.png"}}
    {{chat-message username="John Doe" message="Blah Blah Blah" dispic="http://www.proirrigationwi.com/images/unknown_user.png"}}
    {{chat-message username="John Doe" message="Blah Blah Blah" dispic="http://www.proirrigationwi.com/images/unknown_user.png"}}
  {{/chat-window}}
```

if I replace `{{#chat-window}} {{/chat-window}}`

with

`<div class="chat-window"></div>`

it works fine

But if I try to use the component, the overflow is ignored and the chat messages go way off the screen with no scrolling. Any information would be great thanks.

CSS for chat-window

```
.chat-window {
  height: 75%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Preview:

[image]

If I replace the component with pure html like I said above, it stops and the overflow works as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that using the `class="chat-window"` directly inside the component didn't work for some reason.

But when I did

```
{{#chat-window class="chat-window"}}
```

it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

A component creates its own HTML tag that will contain everything you include in its template.

In your example, the generated HTML probably is something like:

```
<div> <!-- The component div tag -->
    <div class="chat-window"> <!-- Your div tag -->
        <!-- Everything that's rendered in the {{yield}} -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The Ember way to make your component have the HTML structure I think you want is:

```
{{! component hbs file }}
{{chat-message username="John Doe" message="Blah Blah Blah" dispic="http://www.proirrigationwi.com/images/unknown_user.png"}}
{{chat-message username="John Doe" message="Blah Blah Blah" dispic="http://www.proirrigationwi.com/images/unknown_user.png"}}
{{chat-message username="John Doe" message="Blah Blah Blah" dispic="http://www.proirrigationwi.com/images/unknown_user.png"}}
```

```js
/* component js file */
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['chat-window'], // this classes are added to the component HTML tag
  didRender() {
    const el = this.$(this.element); // You can get the tag with `this.element`
    el.scrollTop(el[0].scrollHeight);
  }
});
```